# Jssor Slider 2 sliders combination

Tags: jssor

Is there a way to combine Carousel Slider and Nearby Image Partial Visible Slider? I want to show 6 images - 4 full visible and 2 partial visible at the ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to combine 2 sliders.

Please try to set `$Align` value for the carousel slider.

`$Align` indicates position of the current slide.

```
var options = {
    ...,
    $Align: 50    //50px offset
}
```